# VSCode C++. Referencia no definida para "método de clase"

Tags: c++, vscode

Me encuentro realizando un código básico para una demostración sencilla con el entorno VS Code, poseo instaladas las siguientes extensiones:

- C/C++ (Microsoft)
- C/C++ Makefile Project
- Code Runner
- Makefile Tools

El código es el siguiente:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Dog.h"

int fibonacci(int n){
    if (n < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    if (n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

int main(){
    cout << "\n>>> This is a simple output";

    cout << "\n>>> This is a simple input test, enter the number of times to print 'Lies': ";
    int numberLies = 0;
    cin >> numberLies;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberLies; i++){
        cout << "\nLies";
    }

    cout << "\n>>> Fibonacci 5th digit: " << fibonacci(5);

    cout << "\n>>> Creating a dog";
    Dog *dogOne = new Dog("Fido");
    cout << dogOne->toString();
    dogOne->bark();

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Dog.h**

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef DOG_H
#define DOG_H

#pragma once

class Dog
{
public:
    Dog(string);
    void bark();
    string virtual toString();
    virtual ~Dog();

private:
    string dogName;
};

#endif
```

**Dog.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Dog.h"

Dog::Dog(string _dn)
{
    this->dogName = _dn;
}

void Dog::bark(){
    cout << "\nWoof! Woof! Woof!";
}

string Dog::toString()
{
    stringstream s;
    s << "\n>>>DOG<<<";
    s << "Dog's name is: " << dogName;
    return s.str();
}

Dog::~Dog()
{
    cout << "\nDog::~Dog() dies...";
}
```

Mi archivo **tasks.json**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe compilar archivo activo",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
                // "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compilador: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

La estructura de las carpetas es la siguiente (generada con C/C++ Makefile Project):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro información referente al tema, o al menos no clara. En principio además configuré Code Runner para que guarde todos los archivos antes de ejecutar, además de que sean compilados. Gracias.

Comment: Quizás debas de definir los prototipos de las funciones. En este caso Dog

Comment: Al mencionar "prototipos de las funciones" ¿a qué te refieres¿ y ¿en dónde los definiría? ¿Esos no son los que se encuentran en el archivo de encabezado de Dog?

Comment: El prototipo es un encabezado que se usa a modo de "índice", como se  se tratara de un libro para que el programa pueda saber lo que hay más abajo.

Comment: En este saso irían debajo del Dog

Comment: El código parece estar bien. El problema puede ser que no se esté linkeando el archivo `.o` que corresponde a `dog.cpp`. Ojalá te pudiera ayudar más pero no estoy familiarizado con el método que estás usando para compilar.

Comment: Acabo de compilar tu código con el comando `g++ *.cpp -o main` y funcionó perfectamente. ¿Estás seguro de que la expansión `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp"` funciona correctamente? ¿Y si pruebas listar los archivos `main.cpp` y `dog.cpp` directamente?

Comment: Hola. ¿Listo los archivos reemplazando donde está la sentencia `"${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp"`? ¿Cómo lo haría, así `${main}.cpp, ${Dog}.cpp`?

Comment: El problema es claro, el comando debería ser `g++ main.cpp Dog.cpp -o main`.

Answer (score 0):

Algo más que debas saber:
Code runner solo ejecuta el archivo activo, por lo que dog.cpp no está siendo compilado en ese caso, únicamente main.cpp